# Process files in directories and sub-directories concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

I have a function that checks if files in directory contains some string

```
boolean processFiles(File file, String phrase) {
      if (file.isFile()) {
        return fileContains(file, phrase);
      }

      try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(file.toPath())) {
        for (Path entry: stream) {
          if (processFiles(entry.toFile(), phrase) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
      return false;
}
```

How can I use concurrency in order to improve the performance if I have many directories, sub-directories and files?

I tried to create a thread for processing each sub-directory, but I run out of threads in case there are many nested sub-directories

Using a fixed-size thread pool is also problematic in case we have a many sub-directories
What is the best way for using threads here in order to improve performance?

Comment: The time in which you can crawl folders/process files also largely depends on the speed of the drive in the server/computer. Is the problem you're running into regarding speed CPU related?

Comment: what lets you think you have perf issues? moreover what makes you think that having 100 thread accessing concurrently, you'll get more perfs? disks usually don't like random accesses.

Comment: Try to use a parallel stream. An example can be found here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html

Comment: If your problem is disk IO, adding more threads will not help, really.  If your problem is CPU, adding more threads will also not help.  How many cores does your CPU/system have?  Once your CPU is maxxed out, more threads will slow things down.  What is processFiles doing?  Is it very CPU intensive?

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Using a fixed-size thread pool is also problematic in case we have a many sub-directories

That is an **assumption**, and it is simply: wrong.

You *assume* that the limiting factor is the number of threads. But what makes you think so? It is more likely that *other* elements of this operation will limit the overall performance, such as operating respectively file system activity. To be precise: the drive system below the file system.

You see, you can't make arbitrary problems go *faster* just by throwing an (unlimited) number of threads at them.

If you are serious about performance, stop making assumptions. Instead, start measuring. Test how much time 1 thread needs to "process" a larger tree. Do that repeatedly (most likely file system caching will play a big role here). Then see what changes if you use a fixed thread pool.

My *assumption* is: you will see a certain speedup, but rather quickly, adding more threads will slow down things again. Guessing here: a pool with 4, max 8 threads might give you "optimal" results.

Implementation wise, you could put "new" subdirectories that require crawling on a queue, and then your worker threads take them from the queue for processing.